# imports file structure and Collection definitions

Tags: meteor

Following Meteor docs on how to use the import directory structure, [Example directory layout](https://guide.meteor.com/v1.3/structure.html#example-app-structure).

The illustration says:

> lists.js                 # definition of the Lists collection

Where lists.js path is `app/imports/api/lists/list.js`
The docs indicates that collections definitions need to be in `lib` folder because they need to be loaded on both the client and the server.

What is Meteor new way of achieving this with the imports file structure? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The new way](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html) is basically having 3 main folders:

```
client/main.js
server/main.js
imports
```

Then whatever you need on server, you import in `server/main.js` like:

```
import '/imports/lib/mylibrary.js';
import '/imports/collections/users.js';
```

The same goes for `client/main.js`. It's up to you to decide the structure of `imports` folder, you are the one to decide which files from there to import.

Public files (accessible on client) go to `public`, private files (accessible only on server by [Assets API](https://docs.meteor.com/api/assets.html)) go to `private`. And that's basically enough for starters.

Comment: does that mean that the collection which needs to be loaded for both client and server, the file where said collection is defined needs to be imported to both?

Comment: @FredJ. yes totally correct, you control which collections you need on server, and which you need on client. Because there might be some technical (say, very secret) collections on server that shouldn't even be exposed to client. And vice versa of course

Comment: OK, I got it to work but, only if I remove the `export const` qualifier from the beginning of the line `colName = new Mongo.Collection('colname')` else it will not work.  and in main.js for both client and server I have `import 'path-to-collection-file'. It will not work if I use `import {colname} from 'file-path'` with `export const` in the file where the collection is defined.

Comment: if you `export const` then try to `import colname` (without { and }). This is called named export, there's a description about possible options here in section called "Introducing to using import and export" https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html

Comment: `export default` instead of `export const` worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most common file structure is

1. 'client' (all client side files, can be further grouped for routers,
   appl logic..etc
2. 'server' (all server methods and publications)
3. 'lib' (common files to both client server with the additional value that
   files in here will be loaded first by meteor)
4. 'packages' (all external packages can be put here)
5. Any more folder names at this level will be common to both client and server  but will not be loaded first.